# Graphql javascript input fields - errors

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I am building an Express Graphql backend to support a React with Apollo frontend.  One of my mutations takes in an argument I call Token.  This token is generated by Stripe an has many fields and sub-objects with fields.

I do not need all of these fields to perform my mutation, however, I was getting errors until I created scalar inputs to describe the entire Token object.

Is there a way around this?

Is it possible to set up my mutation to isolate the fields I need and ignore the rest?

[Stripe Docs - Token Object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object)

Some of my code:

```
input Card {
        id: String
        object: String
        address_city: String
        address_country: String
        address_line1: String
        address_line1_check: String
        address_line2: String
        address_state: String
        address_zip: String
        address_zip_check: String
        brand: String
        country: String
        cvc_check: String
        dynamic_last4: String
        exp_month: Int
        exp_year: Int
        fingerprint: String
        funding: String
        last4: String
        metadata: String
        name: String
        tokenization_method: String
    }

    input Token {
        id: String
        object: String
        card: Card
        client_ip: String
        created: Int
        livemode: Boolean
        type: String
        used: Boolean
    }
```

Maybe I should consider setting up a basic express route handler for this, but I would like to keep my site consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the input validation is intentionally very strict. Two possible solutions:

1. Instead of a Token type, you can utilize a String. Apply `JSON.stringify` to your token object on the client side and then parse it inside the resolver. You can also use a custom JSON scalar to the same effect. The biggest drawback with this approach is that you lose all validation of the object itself, although that might not be a huge concern if this is an object that's generated by Stripe anyway.
2. Only include what you need in the Token type, and then use something like `lodash`'s or `ramda`'s `pick` to reduce your object to what your endpoint will actually accept. A little extra work on the client side but probably less painful than having to write a schema for the entire thing. That also means if Stripe adds any properties to the object, it won't wreck havoc with your API call :)

Comment: cool both seem like great ideas. there is one thing i am not sure about though.  since this is my first time playing with Stripe...do they require the token to be 'as is'? basically ruling out a `pick` scenario. testing mode in Stripe is setup such that i can't test for this, but the stringify method seems solid - my main concern being that my graqhql will crash if Stripe makes a small change to their Token.

Comment: Yup I imagine if you're passing the entire token back to Stripe, I would just go with solution #1 :)